# Associated record is not deleted in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I am trying to associate a set of uploaded pictures with a post. In my controller I am using the following code:

```
image_uploads = params[:image_uploads]
iu = ImageUpload.find(image_uploads)
@post.image_uploads = iu
```

While this does make the uploaded images accessible from `@post.image_uploads`, I think it doesn't associate these images with the post because when the post is deleted, the image uploads are not deleted -- even though I have used `:dependent=>:destroy` for their relationships.

```
> Post.first.delete
=>[]
> ImageUpload.all
=> [#<ImageUpload id: 3 ...>]
```

And this is the model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :image_uploads, :dependent => :destroy

end

class ImageUploads < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :post

end
```

What can I do to make sure that cascading deletes work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try instead:

```
Post.first.destroy
```

`destroy` invokes the callbacks defined, whereas `delete` deletes the record directly using SQL without creating an AR object.

Answer (score 0):

What you do seems correct to me. You have a post with image uploads dependent on the post and you should get them deleted when a post is deleted. I could be wrong but i do not see anything.

However, i see something that could cause heavy problems and it could also be the source of your problem(it's a source of many).

You have a model that ends with an S. Not a good idea. Do yourself a favor and change to ImageUpload please :)